# SQLAnywhere CURSOR TEMPORARY TABLE

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere

Im trying to process rows using CURSOR and write values for each row to a temporary table. This works if I use the FOR loop e. g. FOR myLoop AS myCursor CURSOR FOR ... but I want to use the cursor as documented for T-SQL and as soon as I uncomment the line where I try to declare the temporary table I get a cryptic error message:

Could not execute statement.
Syntax error near 'BEGIN' on line 10 (Watcom SQL)
SQLCODE=-131, ODBC 3 State="42000"
Line 10

Also the 'AS' in the column definition in the temp table declaration is not the problem! The three lines that are commented out can be run without any problem if the other lines are removed.

Any Ideas?

```
BEGIN 
-- DECLARE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable (iValue AS INTEGER);
DECLARE @iValue INT;

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ItemValue FROM ListItems;
OPEN myCursor;

FETCH NEXT myCursor INTO @iValue;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) BEGIN 
    FETCH NEXT myCursor INTO @iValue 
END;

CLOSE myCursor;
DEALLOCATE myCursor;

-- SELECT iValue AS [Values] FROM tempTable;
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempTable;
END
```

Thanks

Comment: please update the question with the complete text of the error message

Comment: I think you need to create it, instead of declaring it